# How to argue that $f'(z) = u'(z) + iv'(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $z_0$ so that $f'(z_0) = a_0+i b_0$. I am trying to show that $f'(z_0) = u'(z_0) + iv'(z_0) = a_0+ib_0$. Writing out the definition of the derivative I got

$$\lim_{z \to z_0} \dfrac {f(z) - f(z_0)}{z-z_0} = \lim_{z \to z_0}\left[ \dfrac {u(z)-u(z_0)}{z-z_0} + i\dfrac {v(z)-v(z_0)}{z-z_0}\right] = a_0 + ib_0$$

I would like to split the last limit into  $\lim_{z \to z_0} \dfrac {u(z)-u(z_0)}{z-z_0} +  i\lim_{z \to z_0} \dfrac {v(z)-v(z_0)}{z-z_0}$, but to do that I must first prove that these individual limits exist, and I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm also interested in finding out.

Comment: maybe you can start with the fact that $z_n=x_n+iy_n\to z=x+iy$ iff $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$.

Comment: @Basti Hmm I will have to think about how to prove that fact.

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter Hmm are we sure that this is even true though? If I remember correctly, the Cauchy-Riemann equations say that $f'(z) = \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}$, which I'm not sure is equal to $u'(z)+iv'(z)$.